# VSCode Integrated Terminal Coloring

Tags: terminal, colors, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the Github Dark Dimmed Theme in VSCode.

It looks great except for the Integrated Terminal, the background of executables is quite hard to read (see below). What setting do I need to change in VSCode to change this background color?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it.
I just had to adjust `terminal.ansiGreen` in the settings. I did this by opening the settings in JSON and adding the following

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.ansiGreen": "#a43afa"
    }
```

Not a green anymore, but fixes the issue. Not sure where else this color is used within VSCode, I've not noticed changes anywhere else yet.

Comment: Where to find what these codes refer to? I need to change the color for folder listings in Terminal in VsCode, but can't find the right option.